# Jasper report works fine on Windows but not opening on Ubuntu while deploying

Tags: java, ubuntu, jasper-reports

I came across an issue. I developed Jasper report using iReport 5.6.0, I used NetBeans 8.0.2 (JDK7/1.7). I am using Windows 10. Report works fine on development machine. While deploying it works fine on another Windows 10 machine having java8(91) but It does not work on Ubuntu (JDK7) machine. It does not throw any error also. I am not sure if it is Java problem or some path related issue. I am using sub report also. Find below codes while previewing report:

```
    String sfilename="report";
    String path = "appname/" + sfilename + ".jasper";
    String imgp=("images"); //folder name under appl folder where images are stored

    InputStream reportName = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);

    HashMap param = new HashMap();
    param.put("param1","value1");
    param.put("param2","value2");
    param.put("imgpath",imgp); 
    param.put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "appname/"); 

    try {   
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName, param, conn);  // I observed under Ubuntu it is not going beyond this line

        net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer jv = new net.sf.jasperreports.swing.JRViewer(jp);

 //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
        jf.validate();
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        jf.setLocation(300,100);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setTitle("JASPER REPORT");
```

Comment: You are sure there is no error? What means `it doesn't work`?

Comment: Its not opening. Viewer window is not coming. No error. I am calling Viewer from a Button click event (codes mentioned above).

Comment: Did you try another simple code without using JasperReportsm but with calling Swing?

Comment: not yet I will try and update here

Comment: Well my entire Java application is working fine there (Ubuntu) including Swings. Issue is with Jasper report.

Comment: I removed sub report, images to check if it is path related issue, but still report is not opening on Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Did you try to enable debug logging?

Comment: If it does not work you should have an error, sure you do not have OutOfMemoryError or other uncaught errors..

Comment: Since I deployed this jar on a Ubuntu machine. There I don't have source code, IDE, etc. No error at all. I think it may be related to Fonts.....